# Implement Preferences screen in Xamarin Mac desktop app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I couldn't really find anything about this, that's why i'm asking here.

I'm working on a Mac desktop app using Xamarin, how do I enable/implement the native "Preferences..." screen, which is acessible via Cmd + , ?

By default, this option is disabled and, again, i couldn't find anywhere explaining about this, and i'm not a Xamarin expert, i'm sorry if this is simply not possible.

Thanks in advance

Here is an from Visual Studio app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found in Xamarin.Mac, if a item no load Activated event, it can't click, the default Preferences no, so you can do this:

```
var items = NSApplication.SharedApplication.MainMenu?.Items;//File,Edit,Format,View,Window,Help...
var firstItem = items?[0];
var subMenu = firstItem?.Submenu;
subMenu.Title = "YourAppName";
subMenu.Font = NSFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize( 0);
var menuItemList = subMenu.Items;//About,Line,Preferences,Line,Services... Line also is a item
//Preferences's index is 2, so
menuItemList[2].Activated += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Clickd Preferences");
};
```